# Notepad++ Regex to replace capitalised-case words with space-capital

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use regex and notepad++ to convert "CapitalCaseWords" with "Capital Case Words"
I stole a regex from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158352/php-regex-replace-single-capital-with-space-capital) which does what I need, but I don't know how to convert it into find and replace versions for use in npp...

https://regex101.com/r/Dp95YL/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing with the following lookarounds:

```
Find:   (?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
Replace: (single space)
```

### Demo

Comment: When I try in notepad++ I get this result:CapitalCaseWords ==> C a p i t a l C a s e W o r d s

Comment: That's probably because you are doing a case-insensitive regex replacement.  It needs to be case sensitive.

Comment: @Applez00800 Tick the `Match case` checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, that works. What if I want to add a prefix to it, so that only text with the prefix are replaced? e.g. Alm_CapitalCaseWords ==> Alm_Capital Case Words

Comment: That requirement is much trickier than what you asked (though it might be a logical follow-up for you).  Typically, we would handle it in a programming language by using a regex callback.  First, we would match `\bAlm_\S+`.  Then, we would pass each match to a callback function, and there use my current regex answer.

Comment: @Applez00800 You may replace `(?:Alm_[A-Z][a-z]+|(?<!^)\G)\K([A-Z][a-z]+)` with " \1". [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWRyl2/1). Or maybe `(Alm_[A-Z][a-z]+|(?<!^)\G)([A-Z][a-z]+)` with `\1 \2`.

Comment: @41686d6564 Why don't you post this as answer in [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602594/regex-notepad-to-replace-capitalcasewords-with-space-capital-only-where-a-defi) ?