# How to replace CapitalCaseWords with space-capital only where a defined prefix exists?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Reference info:
[Notepad++ Regex to replace capitalised-case words with space-capital](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602444/notepad-regex-to-replace-capitalised-case-words-with-space-capital)

I need to add to this a requirement that the match contains a defined prefix.
For example I want to replace:

```
"name": "CapitalCaseWords"
"name": "AnotherStringSentence"
"ThisStringShouldntBeReplaced"
```

with:

```
"name": "Capital Case Words"
"name": "Another String Sentence"
"ThisStringShouldntBeReplaced"
```

Where the prefix, in this case, is `"name": "`.

I'm using `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` but it's not working for prefix.

Regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/IpmOnK/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the "Match case" option ticked, you may replace:

```
("name":\ "[A-Z][a-z]+|(?<!^)\G)([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

With:

```
\1 \2
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qpgt8o/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```regex
(                # Start of 1st capturing group.
    "name":\ "   # Match the prefix (including the double quotation).
    [A-Z][a-z]+  # Match an upper-case letter followed by one or more lower-case letters.
|                # Or:
    (?<!^)\G     # Assert position at the end of the previous match.
)                # End of 1st capturing group.
([A-Z][a-z]+)    # 2nd capturing group matching an upper-case letter followed by 
                 # one or more lower-case letters.
```